# livelink ECM: how to attach categories by default to documents

Tags: ecm, livelink

I created a catgory in Livelink ECM system and we need to attach this category to any document being uploaded to the system by default.  We also need to show the attributes (of the attached category) while uploading the file.  How is it possible?